# Are SharkBite plumbing connectors as reliable as soldered connectors?

Tags: plumbing, soldering

Are SharkBite plumbing connectors as reliable as soldered connectors?

Comment: Using a propane torch is more fun though.

Comment: See also http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/207/what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantage-of-using-pushfit-pipe-fittings.

Answer (score 9):

So far they seem to be just as reliable, although given that they've only been on the market for a few years they don't have the same history as soldered connections. Here in the UK almost all new-build houses use push-fit connectors for concealed work as it's much quicker and easier.

You most likely do need to take extra care that the tube is perfectly round for an inch or so at the end, and that there's no bits of swarf, paint or other dirt there. Solder is good at filling in little gaps which push-fit connectors won't seal. On the other hand it's very easy to not heat a solder joint up enough to melt the solder properly, especially in confined spaces.

Obviously, make sure you push them in firmly.

Finally you don't really want to use them for exposed pipes, soldered joints are much neater.

Answer (score 7):

I've not used Shark Bite, but I have used other push fit connectors and as long as you make sure that you push the pipes firmly into the connectors they do the job they're intended for.

I haven't had any leaks or other problems with them.

Another advantage is that you can rotate the pipes and fittings once they're in place so if you have a tight or awkward space to work in you're less restricted.

If you're not confident about your soldering skills then using compression or push fit connectors is probably a better idea as you can sort them out after the water's turned back on without necessarily having to drain the system again.

Answer (score 4):

I've had a few SharkBite connectors installed for a couple years without any leaks. They are pricey but save a lot of time when trying to make repairs or otherwise plumb in tight spaces. In fact, I've seen more leaks from improper solders that then have to be re-soldered than I have from SharkBites, primarily because tight spaces can inhibit applying the torch/flame correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I've had Sharkbites both to Pex and copper in our house for about 8 years including on our boiler copper and Pex O2. Haven't had any leaks so far. Cleaned all the copper with steel wool so it was shiny with no imperfections and de-burred and made sure the Pex was good as well with no scratches and that both copper and Pex were cut straight and fully seated. I think these things are key to them lasting with no leaks. Even a little off in the cut may be why some leak or if you don't clean the copper or it is not round or has imperfections at the point of contact. Just my opinion as I'm not a plumber but a 40 plus year general contractor/carpenter contractor. I only do minor plumbing and electrical, nothing major. I use the pros when I need them which is 95% of the time. I had one leak right after putting it on but it was a pin hole you couldn't see in the brass elbow. Put a new one in and took the old back and got a new one in it's place. I know a lot of plumbers don't like them and are using press fittings. There's good and bad in everything and most of the time it boils down to correct installation and taking time to do it right.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Answer (score 1):

The previous cheapy shut off valve to my toilet had seized. There was no way I could solder a new pipe because whoever installed the pipe didn't leave much room.  I replaced it with a shark bite 4 years ago and it has not yet leaked. What I don't know is will be ok in 10 years. Like you car rubber seals dry up and there is a rubber o-ring that provides the tight seal. You would think that whoever designed these fittings would provide a wider rubber seal and perhaps a longer sleeve for the pipe to fit in....right now the sleeve is less than 1"....imagine if it was say 1.5"and there was more rubber seal for it to grip on.

That being said, my father redid all the plumbing in his house back in 1972.....when I sold the house after he died not one pipe was leaking....all the pipes were solder and amazingly he had installed some compression shut off valves which did not leak or show signs of fatigue. They've be known to fail. I just don't know how the shark bit value will fare out.

The way I look at it is if I have to replace it every 5 years even at $15 its cheaper than a plumber.....but I am also concerned about the plastic collar they use....plastic as we all know gets brittle over time.....if it ever cracked on its own you'd have one hell of a leak. I guess we are all going to have to wait say 10 years to see what the failure rate is on these push on fittings. There is no way I would trust them in a concealed area....image the mess to cut through drywall to fix a leak.

Comment: It shouldn't be a rubber seal.  Probably nylon, silicon, or some other modern material.

Answer (score 0):

I think any connection will eventually fail. Shark Bite fittings have been slowly taking over in my 35 year old plumbing system and working just fine on hot and cold water.  Expensive, simple, fast and you can put them on with water running out the end. Try that with a soldered joint. Time will tell.

Answer (score 0):

I have only one experience with the push on fittings, on a refrigerator water/icemaker connection.  Connected a valve to copper stub which failed although the stub was cleaned well.  I went back and soldered the connection--no problems.  I am converting to Pex and crimps--not clamps-would not trust them.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer, but it isn't clear; are you saying some types of SharkBite are good and some are bad? Would you clarify which? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Comment: I like the pex and crimp connectors not the push on which are expensive and in my experience are not reliable on copper,  they may do better with the pex tubing.

Comment: Thanks. Would you edit this into your answer? Comments aren't meant to be part of a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

For emergencies only lol. Also depends. A real plumber would use it but in certain situations. also upscale the proper fix.  Now The industrial sharkbites were u need to use the crimp tool hand or pneumatic is A ok depending on preassure rating I'd say and overall use any wheres.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It's really hard to see how this answers the original question; would you edit it a bit to make it clearer? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.